# Changing the translucency of a UINavigationBar has the opposite effect

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

I have a very simple setup, an initial navigation controller, a simple view controller as the root. I change the navigation bar's color here.

```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      makeNavigationBar()
   }

   func makeNavigationBar() {
      guard let navigationBar = navigationController?.navigationBar else {
         return
      }
      navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.someColor()
      navigationBar.translucent = true
   }
```

The bizarre thing is this - changing the `translucent` property seems to have the opposite effect, as per the image. Why is this happening? What should I do to have this work as advertised?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, it turned out that the real issue was the background color of my main view. I've set it's RGB value manually using Interface Builder's color picker. While I would set the navigation bar's color using `UIColor` programatically. I don't know why would they produce different results, but after I changed the color profile inside the picker, everything now matches.

Just to make it clear:

- previous value was sRGB
- new, correct value is Generic RGB

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In my experience you also need to set the navigationBar.barStyle to UIBarStyle.BlackTranslucent

**Code**

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle       = UIBarStyle.BlackTranslucent
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.translucent    = false
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor   = UIColor.whiteColor()

}
```

**Results when toggling true/false**
I have used white & grey to exaggerate the effect

= true
[image]

= false
[image]

From the horse's mouth so to speak:

```
@availability(iOS, introduced=2.0)
class UINavigationBar : UIView, NSCoding, UIBarPositioning,   NSObjectProtocol {

var barStyle: UIBarStyle
unowned(unsafe) var delegate: UINavigationBarDelegate?

/*
 New behavior on iOS 7.
 Default is YES.
 You may force an opaque background by setting the property to NO.
 If the navigation bar has a custom background image, the default is inferred 
 from the alpha values of the image—YES if it has any pixel with alpha < 1.0
 If you send setTranslucent:YES to a bar with an opaque custom background image
 it will apply a system opacity less than 1.0 to the image.
 If you send setTranslucent:NO to a bar with a translucent custom background image
 it will provide an opaque background for the image using the bar's barTintColor if defined, or black
 for UIBarStyleBlack or white for UIBarStyleDefault if barTintColor is nil.
 */
@availability(iOS, introduced=3.0)
var translucent: Bool // Default is NO on iOS 6 and earlier. Always YES if barStyle is set to UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent

// Pushing a navigation item displays the item's title in the center of the navigation bar.
// The previous top navigation item (if it exists) is displayed as a "back" button on the left.
func pushNavigationItem(item: UINavigationItem, animated: Bool)
func popNavigationItemAnimated(animated: Bool) -> UINavigationItem? // Returns the item that was popped.

var topItem: UINavigationItem? { get }
var backItem: UINavigationItem? { get }

var items: [AnyObject]!
func setItems(items: [AnyObject]!, animated: Bool) // If animated is YES, then simulate a push or pop depending on whether the new top item was previously in the stack.

/*
 The behavior of tintColor for bars has changed on iOS 7.0. It no longer affects the bar's background
 and behaves as described for the tintColor property added to UIView.
 To tint the bar's background, please use -barTintColor.
 */
var tintColor: UIColor!
@availability(iOS, introduced=7.0)
var barTintColor: UIColor? // default is nil

/* In general, you should specify a value for the normal state to be used by other states which don't have a custom value set.

 Similarly, when a property is dependent on the bar metrics (on the iPhone in landscape orientation, bars have a different height from standard), be sure to specify a value for UIBarMetricsDefault.
 */
```

Comment: I don't see the connection here, please help me with that.

Comment: Added ref to Apple's class ref. see https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationBar_Class/index.html for more.

Comment: OK, I've tested this and it is incorrect and has no effect, plus the `barStyle` you're referring to is deprecated.

Comment: I have updated my answer with an example and screen shots. I am also not receiving a depreciated warning in Xcode 7 beta 4.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), forBarMetrics: UIBarMetrics.Default)
navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
navigationBar.translucent = true
```

Comment: Did you look at the image? Your answer is saying what I already have in my question.